# validates specific attribute of associated model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What's the simplest railsy way to validate an attribute of an associated model?

```
Item
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  # AND the "is_photographer" column for that user must be true

User
  has_many :items
  # can be a regular user or a photographer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
validate :user_is_photographer, :if => :user

def user_is_photographer
  errors.add(:user, "should be a photographer") unless user.is_photographer
end
```